# sql sum partition over two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|  sell | sell_code| buy   | buy_code|   date_time     |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  100  |   usd   |  150   |  eur    |  20/10/2020 09:20
|  50   |   gbp   |  114   |  eur    |  20/10/2020 11:20
|  80   |   eur   |  null  |  null   |  20/10/2020 15:40
|  null |   null  |  80    |  usd    |  21/10/2020 09:20
|  100  |   usd   |  80    |  gbp    |  21/10/2020 13:30
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to sum over partition by sell and buy columns when code same , and sell amount as '+' and buy amount as '-'

want result like that (mssql 2008+)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|sell|sell_code| buy |buy_code|date_time       ||balance1|b_code1|balance2|b_code2|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|100 |  usd   |  150 | eur    |20/10/2020 09:20||    100 | usd   |-150    | eur   |
|50  |  gbp   |  114 | eur    |20/10/2020 15:40||     50 | gbp   |-264    | eur   |
|80  |  eur   |  null| null   |20/10/2020 15:40||   -184 | eur   | null   | null  |  
|null|  null  |  80  | usd    |21/10/2020 09:20||   null | null  |  20    | usd   |
|100 |  usd   |  80  | gbp    |21/10/2020 13:30||    120 |  usd  | -30    | gbp   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

calculating like that

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  sell | sell_code| buy   | buy_code|   date_time     |||balance1       |b_code1|balance2  |b_code2|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  100  |   usd   |  150   |  eur    |  20/10/2020 09:20||    100       | usd   |-150       | eur   |
|  50   |   gbp   |  114   |  eur    |  20/10/2020 11:20||     50       | gbp   |(-150)-114 | eur   |
|  80   |   eur   |  null  |  null   |  20/10/2020 15:40||(-150-114)+80 | eur   | null      | null  |  
|  null |   null  |  80    |  usd    |  21/10/2020 09:20||   null       | null  |(100)-80   | usd   |
|  100  |   usd   |  80    |  gbp    |  21/10/2020 13:30||(100-80)+100  | usd   | (50)-80   | gbp   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any ideas?

Comment: depends on what RDMS you have. Indicate it in your question (including version)

Comment: Please explain the calculations.  They are not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long efforts I solved  with this way

```
select sell,sell_code,buy,buy_code,a.date_time,balance1,bcode1,balance2,bcode2 from
(select * from @t)a
left join
(select sum(balance)over (partition by code order by date_time) as balance1,code as bcode1,date_time from
(select sell as balance,sell_code as code,date_time  from @t
union all
select 0-buy as balance,buy_code as code,date_time  from @t)x)b
on b.date_time=a.date_time and a.sell_code=b.bcode1
left join
(select sum(balance)over (partition by code order by date_time) as balance2,code as bcode2,date_time from
(select sell as balance,sell_code as code,date_time  from @t
union all
select 0-buy as balance,buy_code as code,date_time  from @t)x)c
on c.date_time=a.date_time and a.buy_code=c.bcode2
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11af5b08a97e0867550ef75dd54d0a75)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not handling the `NULL`s in `join`. I modified your code slightly as follows:

```
select c.sell,c.sell_code,c.buy,c.buy_code,c.date_time, b.balance as balance1,b.code, b2.balance balance2, b2.code 
from
MyTable c
left join
(
    select sum(balance) over(partition by code order by convert(datetime, date_time, 104)) as balance,code,date_time 
    from
    (   select sell as balance,sell_code as code,date_time  from MyTable
        union all
        select 0-buy as balance,buy_code as code,date_time  from MyTable
    )a
)b
on isnull(b.code, '')=isnull(c.sell_code, '') and b.date_time=c.date_time 
left join
(
    select sum(balance) over(partition by code order by convert(datetime, date_time, 104)) as balance,code,date_time 
    from
    (   select sell as balance,sell_code as code,date_time  from MyTable
        union all
        select 0-buy as balance,buy_code as code,date_time  from MyTable
    )a
)b2
on isnull(b2.code, '')=isnull(c.buy_code, '') and b2.date_time=c.date_time 
order by convert(datetime, c.date_time, 104)
```

db<>fiddle **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97280b3789603fa7c1202cfce6367eca)**.

Comment: @zuluman You copied the answer code into your question, doesn't it give the expected result?